# faiss: How to retrieve vector by id from python

Tags: python, c++, swig, faiss

I have a faiss index and want to use some of the embeddings in my python script. Selection of Embeddings should be done by id. As faiss is written in C++, swig is used as an API.

I guess the function I need is [reconstruct](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/main/faiss/Index.h) :

```
/** Reconstruct a stored vector (or an approximation if lossy coding)
     *
     * this function may not be defined for some indexes
     * @param key         id of the vector to reconstruct
     * @param recons      reconstucted vector (size d)
     */
    virtual void reconstruct(idx_t key, float* recons) const;
```

Therefore, I call this method in python, for example:

```
vector = index.reconstruct(0)
```

But this results in the following error:

> vector = index.reconstruct(0)
> File
> "lib/python3.8/site-packages/faiss/**init**.py",
> line 406, in replacement_reconstruct
> self.reconstruct_c(key, swig_ptr(x))   File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/faiss/swigfaiss.py",
> line 1897, in reconstruct
> return _swigfaiss.IndexFlat_reconstruct(self, key, recons)
>
> TypeError: in method 'IndexFlat_reconstruct', argument 2 of type
> 'faiss::Index::idx_t' python-BaseException

Has someone an idea what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: I guess `reconstruct` replaces a vector in an index. Seems like It requires a vector as a second parameter

Comment: reconstruct() works for me. Maybe you didn't install faiss properly. You better install it by conda instead of pip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only way I found manually.

```
import faiss
import numpy as np

a = np.random.uniform(size=30)
a = a.reshape(-1,10).astype(np.float32)
d = 10
index = faiss.index_factory(d,'Flat', faiss.METRIC_L2)
index.add(a)

xb = index.xb
print(xb.at(0) == a[0][0])
```

Output:

```
True
```

You can get any vector with a loop

```
required_vector_id = 1
vector = np.array([xb.at(required_vector_id*index.d + i) for i in range(index.d)])
    
print(np.all(vector== a[1]))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the embeddings that you added to an index by using this,

```
# Number of docs added to your index
num_docs = index.ntotal
# Get the dimension of your embeddings
embedding_dimension = index.d

embeddings = faiss.rev_swig_ptr(index.get_xb(), num_docs*embedding_dimension).reshape(num_docs, embedding_dimension)
```

**Reference**

- [FAISS test case in github repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/687457b2f4ab7c93f553442a283afe46156e5e91/tests/test_build_blocks.py#L69)

Answer (score 1):

We could use `reconstruct_n` to create an approximation of the embedding vectors:

```
reconstruct_n = replacement_reconstruct_n(self, n0=0, ni=-1, x=None)
    Approximate reconstruction of vectors `n0` ... `n0 + ni - 1` from the index.
    Missing vectors trigger an exception.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    n0 : int
        Id of the first vector to reconstruct (default 0)
    ni : int
        Number of vectors to reconstruct (-1 = default = ntotal)
    x : array_like, optional
        pre-allocated array to store the results
    
    Returns
    -------
    x : array_like
        Reconstructed vectors, size (`ni`, `self.d`), `dtype`=float32
```

Assuming FAISS index was already on disk for a document count of 3153, the following snippet reads the index and calls  `db.index.reconstruct_n` with default arguments to generate the embeddings:

```
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS

embeddings_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
db = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embeddings_model)
embeddings_vector = db.index.reconstruct_n()
```

Example output:

```
>>> db.index.reconstruct_n()
array([[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                nan,         nan],
       [ 0.07472705, -0.0020752 ,  0.01514121, ..., -0.04662867,
        -0.047438  ,  0.00087454],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                nan,         nan],
       ...,
       [ 0.02280756, -0.0501017 , -0.02089807, ..., -0.02345564,
        -0.00601421, -0.02996513],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                nan,         nan]], dtype=float32)
>>> db.index.reconstruct_n().shape
(3153, 768)
```

And for a specific vector:

```
idx = 0
db.index.reconstruct_n(idx, 1)[0]
```

Comment: What are we to make of all those nans in the output? Does it have to do with the index type used?